# How to structure an array in php for specific use

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Am trying to arrange data's that i retrieved from database in an an array, but it can't get the array structure the way i want it to look like.

```
<?php
$ujahdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM productcomment WHERE code = :code");
$ujahdb->bind(":code", $GetProductCode);
$ujahdb->execute();
$productComments = $ujahdb->getAll();
$ujahdb->free();
if(!empty($productComments)){
//require_once('ini.config/ProductStarRating.php');
$rateing['comments'] = '';
    foreach($productComments as $com){
      $rateing[]['name'] = $com->commenter_name;
      $rateing['star'] = $com->comment_rate;
      print_r($rateing);
  }
}
?>
```

This is the array am getting

> Array ( [comments] => [0] => Array ( [name] => Peter ) [star] => 3 )
>   Array ( [comments] => [0] => Array ( [name] => Jonh ) [star] => 2 [1]
>   => Array ( [name] => Peter ) )

I need something like this-

> Array([comments] => Array([0] => Array([name] => Peter [star] => 3)
>   [1] => Array([name] => Jonh [star] => 2)))

Any idea how to make this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it

```
<?php
$ujahdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM productcomment WHERE code = :code");
$ujahdb->bind(":code", $GetProductCode);
$ujahdb->execute();
$productComments = $ujahdb->getAll();
$ujahdb->free();
if(!empty($productComments)){
   //require_once('ini.config/ProductStarRating.php');

   foreach($productComments as $com){
      $rateing = [];
      $rateing["comments"] = [
            "name" => $com->commenter_name,
            "star" => $com->comment_rate,
         ];
      print_r($rateing);
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is still repeating the comment which is the main array name here is the output `Array ( [comments] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Peter [star] => 3 ) ) ) Array ( [comments] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Peter [star] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Peter [star] => 2 ) ) ) `

Comment: It's printing because you are printing in every iteration of the loop, if you print_r outside the loop it will show only once. I've edited my answer but I'm starting to think that my original one was right